# Dynamic class name ngRepeat root element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use the model to add class names to each root element of my ngRepeat. I need each li to have a unique class name. Is there anyway to do this?

**class="{{item.clazz}}"**

```
<nav id="main-menu">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in menus[0].items" class="{{item.clazz}}">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" slidedown-toggle><i class="{{item.icon}}"></i><span>{{item.name}}</span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li ng-repeat="link in item.items[0].items">
                    <a href="{{link.link}}">{{link.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>


items: [{
            title: 'About Us',
            icon: 'icon-about',
            clazz: 'about-us-menu',
            items: [{
                name: 'Who are we?',
                icon: '',
                link: '#'
            }, {
                name: 'Our Partners',
                icon: '',
                link: '#'
            }, {
                name: 'Careers',
                icon: '',
                link: '#'
            }, {
                name: 'Stuff from CMS',
                icon: '',
                link: '#'
            }]
        }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code you have clazz on the top level object but your ng-repeat is looking at `item.clazz` which would return undefined.

So either items array objects should look something similar to:

```
items: [{
        name: 'Who are we?',
            icon: '',
            link: '#',
            clazz: 'unique-class-name'
        }, {
            name: 'Our Partners',
            icon: '',
            link: '#',
            clazz: 'unique-class-name'
        }]
```

Or if you want 'about-us-menu' class applied to all the li then use the following:

`<li ng-repeat="item in menus[0].items" class="{{menus[0].clazz}}">`

Comment: They did not work for me. I tried class="{{menus[0].clazz}}" and I tried class="{{menus[$index].clazz}}". For now, I just ended up putting class="main-menu-{{$index}}" and then using the awful class in my css: li.main-menu-3 to reference the one element I need to style differently than the others.

Comment: I cant see exactly how you have your set up, but I've created a fiddle showing both ways: http://jsfiddle.net/VnNVA/

(Ctrl has the class on the top level as you have the obj at the moment, CtrlClazz has the clazz on the item obj)

Comment: What! That doesn't work for my environment. So I must have some kind of version issue. Crap. Thanks a ton for putting that fiddle together for me.

Comment: Nope...I am an idiot. I had the clazz property in the wrong level. You rock sir.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [`ngClass` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

If you in your controlle have

```
$scope.someClasses = "foo bar";
```

And in your view:

```
<div ng-class="someClasses">
```

Then the classes `foo` and `bar` will be applied to your `div`.

Comment: Not sure how this would apply to ngRepeat but thanks

Comment: @TonySmith Then you will have to be more specific about what you want.